# How do I make an engine to change the current area of a game in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently in the process of learning Python using the book Learn Python The Hard Way. On exercise 43, I have been asked to create my own game and I have to follow these rules:

- I have to use multiple files.
- I have to use a class for each area my character can go to.

In my game I have different areas which are represented as classes and I need an engine to run them. The engine should set the starting area, and change the area when my character types the correct command. I don't understand how to create an engine, and I have seen some online but I could never understand how they worked. I've spent hours trying to make one for myself and I just couldn't do it.

This is the code for the different areas:
areas.py:

```
# Jungle area's are numbered like a keypad on a phone.
from engine import *

class Jungle8(object):
    print "\nYou are south of the jungle.\n"
class Jungle1(object):
    print "\nYou are northwest of the jungle.\n"
class Jungle2(object):
    print "\nYou are north of the jungle."
    print "The Monkey Elder is waiting for you.\n"
class Jungle3(object):
    print "\nYou are northeast of the jungle.\n"
class Jungle4(object):
    print "\nYou are west of the jungle.\n"
class Jungle5(object):
    print "\nYou are in the center of the jungle.\n"
class Jungle6(object):
    print "\nYou are east of the jungle."
    print "You can see a cave with a locked door.\n"
class Jungle7(object):
    print "\nYou are southwest of the jungle.\n"
class Jungle9(object):
    print "\nYou are southeast of the jungle.\n"
```

This is the code for the engine, which is basically empty:

```
from areas import *

class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # No idea on what to do at this point.
```

Is there a way to run a class? If I was using functions for the rooms i'd be able to do this, but classes have just confused me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. A class is callable (a function) when it has a `__call__` method.

```
class Jungle6():
    def __call__(self):
        print "\nYou are east of the jungle."
        print "You can see a cave with a locked door.\n"
```

as an example.

You then just call the instance:

```
j = Jungle6()
j()
```

Comment: That should exist in python 2. I edited my answer for hopefully more clarity.

Comment: Thank you so much! This should help me a lot!